# Counting line segments efficiently

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I'm trying to solve [Slicing Paradise](http://orac.amt.edu.au/cgi-bin/train/problem.pl?problemid=569&set=aio11sen) from the Australian Informatics Training Site. The idea is that you have a sequence of blocks (actually forest in the statement, and `land` in my code), and at each time a block gets removed (or converted to a resort), which might increase or decrease the number of runs of consecutive (forest) blocks. I'm to compute the all-time maximal number of runs. Input is the number of blocks N, followed by N lines giving the time of removal for each of the blocks. Times are consecutive integers starting at 1.

My code works fine (I think) but it's too slow for some of the larger cases. Can someone suggest a simple fast working solution please, or any improvements that can be made to mine to make it run in O(N)?

## Slow solution

```
#include <cstdio>

FILE* infile;
FILE* outfile;
int N,c,j,l,best;

int main(){
    infile=fopen("slicein.txt","r");
    outfile=fopen("sliceout.txt","w");

    fscanf(infile,"%d\n",&N);

    int land[N+1];
    int location[N+1];

    for (int i=1;i<=N;i++){
        fscanf(infile,"%d\n",&location[i]);
        land[i]=0;
    }

    j=1;l=1;c=1;

    for (int i=1;i<=N;i++){
        if (location[i]==j){
            land[i]=1;
            if (land[i+1]!=1 && land[i-1]!=1 && i!=N && i!=1) c++;
            else if (land[i-1]==1 && land[i+1]==1 && i!=N && i!=1) c--;
            j++;
            if (c>best) best=c;
            i=0;
        }
        if (i==N && l!=N*N){
            i=0;
        }
        else if (l==N*N) break;
        l++;
    }

    fprintf(outfile,"%d\n",best);

    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your benchmark that shows that it is "too slow"?

Comment: Without looking too hard at your code, it seems that it runs in O(N), so why is it too slow?

Comment: @Andreas The online judge says it's too slow. If you read the "Constraints" mentioned in the Problem Statement, it says that for 30% of the marks N<=1000. However, for 100% of marks N<=100,000. Here is an image of the judging output so you can see: http://imgur.com/j9lw95Q
o_weisman It's not O(N). It's O(N^2). Look at the integer l. I only break once it's reached the value of N^2.

Comment: Have you tried a profiler to see which bit is slow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have essentially two nested loops, one outer for `j` and one inner for `i`, although you didn't write it that way explicitely. This gives you an O(N) approach to finding the current location, which amounts to an O(N<sup>2</sup>) overall cost.

The essential information is that in each round `j` you need to find the location `i` converted in that round. You can build a map for that while reading the input. Instead of having `location` as a map from position to time, make it a map from time to position:

```
for (int i=1;i<=N;i++){
    int t;
    fscanf(infile,"%d\n",&t);
    location[t] = i;
    land[i]=0;
}
```

Then you can make do with a single O(N) loop, and everything should be fine. Make sure to get the indexing correct, since you seem to be using one-based indexing in some places and zero-based indexing in others.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot figure out your solution but following is an algorithm to do it in **O(nlogn)** :-

> 1. Store tupples (i,time[i]) in vector
> 2. Sort the vector according to time[i]
> 3. maintain a boolean array to check whether a plot is taken.
> 4. taken[i] = false for all i initially
> 5. start constructing plot in sorted order.
> 6. initially forests = 1
> 7. when a plot is constructed check adjacent plots in boolean array.
> 8. if both are occupied then forests = forests - 1
> 9. if one is occupied then no change
> 10. if both are empty forests = forests + 1
> 11. after every construction check if forest id greater than max count.

**Time complexity :-**

```
Sorting takes O(logn)
plot construction in sorted order O(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested here's my answer:

```
#include <cstdio>

FILE* infile;
FILE* outfile;
int N,c,j,l,b,best;

int main(){
infile=fopen("slicein.txt","r");
outfile=fopen("sliceout.txt","w");

fscanf(infile,"%d\n",&N);

int land[N+1];
int location[N+1];
j=1;l=1;c=1;b=1;

for (int i=1;i<=N;i++){
    int t;
    fscanf(infile,"%d\n",&t);
    location[t]=i;
    land[i]=0;
}
for (int i=1;i<=N;i++){
    land[location[i]]=1;
    if (land[location[i]-1]!=1 && land[location[i]+1]!=1 && location[i]!=1 && location[i]!=N) c++;
    else if (land[location[i]-1]==1 && land[location[i]+1]==1 && location[i]!=1 && location[i]!=N) c--;
    else if (land[location[i]-1]==1 && location[i]==N) c--;
    else if (land[location[i]+1]==1 && location[i]==1) c--;
    if (c>best) best=c;
}

fprintf(outfile,"%d\n",best);

fclose(infile);
fclose(outfile);

return 0;}
```

Thanks to MvG for suggesting the algorithm :)

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour: you access `land[location[i]+1]` *before* checking `location[i]!=N`, so you might access beyond the end of the array. Usually this works but strictly speaking you can't rely on this. But there is a way to avoid a lot of case distinctions: make the `land` array of length `N+2` and set `land[0]` and `land[N+1]` to `1`. Then you only need to look at the left and right value, without any special cases for the boundary. You should also improve your indentation, and perhaps use a variable to hold the value of `location[i]` to make things more readable.